# Add library as "Referenced library"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying programatically add library to referenced libraries. Here's my code:

```
String filename = "myfile.jar";
InputStream is;
try {
   is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\" + filename));
   IFile file = project.getFile(filename);
   file.create(is, false, null);

   IPath path = file.getFullPath();                         
   IClasspathEntry[] cpe = javaProject.getRawClasspath();
   List<IClasspathEntry> libraries = Arrays.asList(cpe);                    
   libraries.add(JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(path, null, null));
   try {
        javaProject.setRawClasspath(libraries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[libraries.size()]), null);
   } catch (JavaModelException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
   }
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

But the result seems that:

[image]

---

UPDATE 1.

Here's classpath. It seems that `.classpath` isn't changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con"  path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: This code will not update Eclipse's configuration for your project. It will only add the libraries during runtime.

Comment: @KevinMangold Based on the code in question, it is pretty clear that the code snippet is part of an Eclipse plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works:

```
IClasspathEntry[] entries = javaProject.getRawClasspath();
IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[entries.length + 1];

 System.arraycopy(entries, 0, newEntries, 0, entries.length);

 // add a new entry using the path to the container
 //Path junitPath = new Path("D:\\jarscan.jar");
 IClasspathEntry junitEntry = JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(new Path("D:\\jarscan.jar"), null, null, false);
 newEntries[entries.length] = junitEntry;
 javaProject.setRawClasspath(newEntries, null);
```

More info [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_classpath.htm)

Comment: This isn't really a solution to the original question. You've changed the requirements. Instead of copying the jar into project and then referencing it in portable manner, you are adding an absolute path to project build path.

Comment: >Add library as “Referenced library”.
I didn't write anything about copying *.jar to project. I've just wanted to pind libarary to project as “Referenced library”

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue is with this line:

```
IPath path = file.getFullPath();
```

Try this line instead:

```
IPath path = file.getProjectRelativePath();
```

A good way to debug problems when making changes to project build path is to look at the .classpath file in the project root. This file will show you the exact effect your code is having. Then compare to the effect you get when performing an equivalent operation manually.

Comment: It doesn't work. Library is just copied to root folder of eclipse project. `.classpath` file isn't modified.

Comment: Do you see any exceptions? If .classpath file isn't modified, you aren't accessing the project you think you are accessing. You may need to describe your setup in more detail...

Comment: I didn't see any exceptions. I've pasted source code of my class

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. At this point, I would recommend putting a breakpoint on setRawClasspath() method invocation, stepping into the method and seeing what JDT isn't liking about what you are doing.

Comment: I think that adding libaries in runtime maybe isn't correct... but it's only my guess. I'm not very familiarized with eclipse plugins

Comment: What exactly do you mean "adding libraries in runtime". Please describe your setup in more detail. It is perfectly normal for a plugin to add libraries to a project classpath. In fact, the Build Path dialog itself is in a plugin using the same API as you are using to manipulate the build path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet how to add custom libraries to the project. I hope it helps you to get the idea.

```
// configure class path, source dir and output dir
        final IPath outputpath = project.getFullPath().append(CLASSES);
        final IClasspathEntry classpath1 = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(project.getFullPath().append(customPath));
        final IClasspathEntry[] defaultClasspath = org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PreferenceConstants.getDefaultJRELibrary();
        final IClasspathEntry[] newClasspath = new IClasspathEntry[defaultClasspath.length + 2];
        System.arraycopy(defaultClasspath, 0, newClasspath, 0, defaultClasspath.length);
        newClasspath[defaultClasspath.length] = classpath1;
        javaProject.setRawClasspath(newClasspath, outputpath, null);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Library is just copied to root folder of eclipse project. `.classpath` file isn't modified.